# How to highlight text between two delimiters / tags?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, plugin-vim-surround

How do I **highlight** the block of text between two delimiters / tags / "surroundings"?
(e.g., between matching parentheses **()s**, quotes **""**, html tags **(div../div)**, etc.)
(Or maybe how to **select** the block, if that would have the same effect as highlighting it)

I have the `vim-surround` plugin installed, so that could be used for the solution, or just plain vim is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following commands in normal mode / command mode:
`vit`

(I just discovered that ☝️ answer ☝️ [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039521/how-to-select-the-inner-text-of-an-xml-tag-in-vim))

`:help v`
`:help v_it`  (*inner tag block*)
`:help text-objects`

Comment: I believe `text-objects` is the help topic you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Pak! I've now added it.